# JAXB In JDK21 and Springboot 3.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb

I'm using jdk21 and springboot 3.1.8. Is it okay to use javax.jaxb. Since every packages are moved from javax to jakarta. are there any alternative for marshal and unmarshal. Thanks in advance for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to migrate your project which was supposedly prior to JDK 17. IMO the straightforward approach is to refactor your existing codebase to replace javax.* namespace to jakarta.*.

But if you'd rather use an alternative serialization library, these are great too:

- [Jackson's FasterXML](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml) (You might not need this dependency if you already have spring-boot-starter-web-services)
- [Apache's XMLBeans](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/documentation/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for the solution @Tom. Yes i'm migrating jdk  from 11 to 17 and springboot from 2.6 to 3.2. i replaced javax.* to jakarta.* which is from com.guicedee it started working again.